# Use if statement to judge in the Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I hope to calculate such a formula through GEE：
[image: CSI =]

But I don’t know how to write judgment statements and load this in GEE, Hope you can point out the error. Here is my code:

```
var getcsi = function (image) {
    if (nir.gt.ndwi) {
        var csi_1 = image.expression('sei - nir')
    }
    else {
        var csi_2 = image.expression('sei - ndwi')
    }
    return image;
};
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca7f010a6ccd0b50bb32188bde5c6599

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippet in your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bit too many problems with your code for me to understand how you want this to work exactly. You might want to try using `where()`:

```
image.expression('sei - ndwi', {sei: sei, ndwi: ndwi})
    .where(
      nir.gt(ndwi), 
      image.expression('sei - nir', {sei: sei, nir: nir})
    )
```